Issue with GUI Application - Update from VS2015 to VS2022 - C++ Application
There is a GUI Application that is based on C++ that we are trying to update from VS2015 to VS2022. The application after the upgrade is not functioning as expected. The executable does not even open although the build is successful. In VS2015 though, the build is working perfectly on the expected lines.
While trying to debug the code with the VS Debugger goes through the following function :
int __cdecl TestStartup()
{
  return WinMainCRTStartup();
}

WinMainCrtStartup() is supposed to call a function called WinMain(). During this stage simultaneously on the Visual Studio debugger, its showing that its trying to open a set of DLLs before breaking. We could observe a difference in the working VS2015 vs the non functioning VS2022 on the list of DLLs that is loaded from C:\Windows\System32 shown on Output Section in VS Debugger
VS2015 :

Ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, KernelBase.dll, gdi32.dll, win32u.dll,
gdi32full.dll, msvcp_win.dll, ucrtbase.dll , user32.dll, advapi32.dll,
msvcrt.dll, sechost.dll, bcrypt.dll, rpcrt4.dll, shell32.dll,
psapi.dll , winmm.dll , wininet.dll, imm32.dll, Uxtheme.dll,
Combase.dll, Kernel.appcore.dll, Ole32.dll, Comctl32.dll,
oleaut32.dll, shlwapi.dll, bcryptprimitives.dll, windows.storage.dll,
WinTypes.dll, SHCore.dll, cmedit64d.dll, GdiPlus.dll, msctf.dll,
TextShaping.dll, TextInputFramework.dll , CoreMessaging.dll,
CoreUIComponents.dll, Cryptbase.dll, AudioSes.dll, winmmbase.dll ,
MMDevAPI.dll, avrt.dll, ksuser.dll, devobj.dll, cfgmgr32.dll,
cfgmgr32.dll, msacm32.dll, midimap.dll, clbcatq.dll, powrprof.dll,
umpdc.dll, ResourcePolicyClient.dll

VS2022 :

Ntdll.dll, kernel32.dll, KernelBase.dll, gdi32.dll, win32u.dll,
gdi32full.dll, msvcp_win.dll, ucrtbase.dll , user32.dll, advapi32.dll,
msvcrt.dll, sechost.dll, bcrypt.dll, rpcrt4.dll, shell32.dll,
psapi.dll , winmm.dll , wininet.dll, imm32.dll

We are trying to fix this issue while updating to VS2022. Tried checking various project configurations but unable to figure out a specific reason for this issue

This seems to be a case of DLL hell. You are compiling with headers that are valid for one version of a DLL, but then loading a different version of that DLL. This quickly results in a crash.

The application after the upgrade... -- If you installed VS 2022 on the same computer as VS 2015, did you make sure you installed VS 2022 in a completely separate directory?  I have 4 versions on my machine (VS 2015, VS 2017, VS 2019, VS 2022), and have no issue compiling, building, and running on each one. --We are trying to fix this issue -- Install VS 2022 on a "clean" machine that doesn't have VS 2015 installed.  Have you tried this?

I'd use a tool like Dependency Walker to help figure out which DLL isn't loading, causing the app to silently fail to launch.
